# I signed my car over to boyfriend, now he is threatening to take it away

Tags: united-states, auto-loan, title

I fell behind on my mortgage as I was hurt by Kaiser in a procedure and had 3 surgeries. I was going to move in with my boyfriend and he offered to give me the money to catch up my mortgage. I suggested we sign over the car, have him get a loan with a great rate and Even put my house with $167 equity in his name and rent out my house. Money could be taken out of the house to pay the car. Well, things didn't work out as planned, the car was signed over and he got a loan but he decided he didn't want to transfer my house and he wanted to break up.

We had no contract for this instance and with me being disabled I couldn't afford the payment. He agreed to pay for a few months until I could assume payments. We got back together a few months later but the tension from the car is not a good thing and causes some bad feelings. He is now threatening to pick up the car in a few days and it isn't fair.

I had an inheritance and planned for the car to be paid and filed Chapter 13, but my case was dismissed on a technicality which forced me to use the entire inheritance to save my house. I would love nothing more than to pay and am actually starting a new business that has promise. My car is 5 years old and was paid off at year 3 when I became injured so I didn't have to worry about payments not knowing what I would be facing medically.

I would never have agreed to an agreement with these terms and it doesn't seem fair. He also changed his mind not even 1 month after the car loan funded which wasn't cool. I also don't want to make him pay the loan. I know now I should have accepted his gift to catch up my mortgage and left my car out of danger.
I am not sure if I have any options but losing my car but if anyone can offer any suggestion I would be very grateful.

Comment: I think this should be migrated to law.SE

Comment: Are you looking for financial or relationship advice?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about an interpersonal relationship.

Comment: Sounds like a Judge Judy case ...

Answer (score 7):

Make sure I am reading this correctly.  You signed the car over to you BF, he took a loan against it and gave you the money?

If so, you sold him the car and any use you have had of it since was at his consent.  Outside of a written contract saying otherwise (and possibly even with one) it is now his car to do with as he pleases.

It sucks that things are not working out in the manner you intended at the time, but that is the reality of the situation.

Comment: @Wilson Rozwel is right.  Just change the way you view the situation.  You sold him the car.  He took a loan on it (his business, his right).  He is letting you use the car.  He can't afford the loan and needs to sell the car because the note is harming his financial situation.  Now maybe you can see both sides.  Now, I have a question for you.  Do you NEED a car?  Sounds like you're working from home.  Consider adjusting your living situation so that you do not need a car.  If necessary, move to a location with access to public transportation or where you can walk/bike to grocery store, etc.